# Multiple !important class declarations and precedence

Tags: css

Theoretically speaking, if you had this scenario:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .class1 {
        color:#F00 !important;
    }
    .class2 {
        color:#00F !important;
    }
</style>

<p class="class2 class1">Test</p>
```

Which color should take precedence? How do browsers determine precedence in this scenario?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Nice first question. Indeed, it's `class2` that gets used: http://jsfiddle.net/yd6Gy/ But why? Interested to see what comes up.

Comment: This question highlights why I feel that the `!important` flag was poorly designed.

Comment: @Spudley you are definitely right about that; however, as far as I understand the issue, `!important` is not important here. The same phenomenon would occur if you'd remove both of them

Comment: I think `!important` is as stupid as `goto` in C.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

According to this source: http://www.boogiejack.com/CSS_4.html

class2 should override the class1 styling.

> Order of Specification: As a last
>   resort, when all other conflict
>   resolution specifications cannot
>   determine which style should take
>   precedence, the last style specified
>   will be the style used.

Comment: +1 this is the in-depth info I was hoping for. The [MDC](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:0fgzBZMKlXEJ:https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Common_CSS_Questions+css+multiple+classes+w3c&cd=6&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de&source=www.google.de) puts it even more clearly: `If the same property is declared in both rules, the conflict is resolved first through specificity, then according to the order of the CSS declarations. The order of classes in the class attribute is not relevant. `

Comment: It seems this won't happen if you add 'class2' using JQuery .addClass method.

Answer (score 15):

With two equally weighted selectors, the behavior is the same whether you apply `!important` to both or omit it from both.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .class1 {
        color: #F00; /* red */
    }
    .class2 {
        color: #00F; /* blue */
    }
</style>
```

The order of classes in the html class attribute is irrespective of each class selector's specificity level.

```
<p class="class2 class1">Test X</p>
<p class="class1 class2">Test Y</p>
```

Output

- Test X → blue
- Test Y → blue

If you use `!important` on just one selector class, then that one will take precedence (because it takes on a higher level of specificity).

Answer (score 7):

Since classes are all "equal important" when added to an element it doesn't matter in which order you assign them to your paragraph.

In this case, `color` in `.class1` and `.class2` are both declared as important, but because .class2 was declared after .class1 the browser will show your paragraph in blue, since it overwrites the declared color from `.class1`

Also, have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/3uPXx/1/
You can see it doesn't matter in which order you declare the class on your paragraph. Since both classes define the same attribute (`color`) it will be overwritten be the class which is declared last.

The only thing that can overwrite this is an inline-style with !important as you can see in the fiddle.