# Why do CSS Frameworks use !important tags unnecessarily?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, zurb-foundation, css-frameworks, cascade-framework

This is more of a debate than a question but I feel that there isn't a lot on the internet that covers this topic.

For example foundation comes with hundreds of !important tags for things that in my eyes do not need them:

```
.text-center { text-align: center !important; }
```

There is loads of css that is simular to this which in my point of view is bad practise and the question I'd like to answer is why do css frameworks use them at all? Bootstrap and Foundation are two main css frameworks that both use them.

I've always been told that using important tags in css is very bad practise and should only be used for IE.

Comment: maybe it's because those key selectors must not be overwritten, or the layout will corrupt / distort .

Comment: My understanding (and I might be wrong) is that in those frameworks they are used to override previously defined styles for different devices (i.e. media queries)

Comment: My thought is that a lot of css frameworks are more suitable for fast prototipation rather than for real production code. If you feel that the code is not performant then you have probably achieved enough knowledge on the subject to move on and use something else.

Comment: `!important` is not intended for IE only, whoever told you that didn't know what they were saying. It is true though that you should avoid to use it as it is just boosting specificity all the way up and you should try to avoid that. Frameworks most probably use this for this exact purpose : overruling most of the rules that could be defined some place else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you write your own CSS you have the freedom to add more specific rules whenever needed:

```
.center        { text-align: center; }
.foobar        { text-align: left; }
.foobar.center { text-align: center; }
```

However, the CSS framework cannot predict how you will arrange your HTML. So it is easier to do `!important` instead of generating thousands of combinations of more specific rules. Example:

```
.center               { text-align: center; }
.foobar               { text-align: left; }
.barbaz               { text-align: right; }
 /*
  * assuming .center must be centered regardless of other rules and
  * !important must be avoided at the same time, we need to do this
  */
.foobar.center        { text-align: center; }
.barbaz.center        { text-align: center; }
.foobar.barbaz.center { text-align: center; }
```

Comment: Your answer makes the most sense to me. I'd upvote it but I haven't got enough reputation.

Comment: This is a horrible answer. No bigger website should ever use specific style than reusable styles. For reusable responsive styles, there should be media queries defined without important, if there is important, not only custom css can't override that for responsive purpose, even JS can't do interaction to override that class without using 'important'.

Comment: @user2734550 the question is why some frameworks such as twitter bootstrap use `!important`even though its use is discouraged. Can you answer that?

Answer (score 2):

Is because you can have in your code st. like this:

```
<style>
#aside p {text-align: right;}
.text-center {text-align: center} /* without important text will be aligned to right */
</style>

<div id="aside">
    <p>right-aligned text</p>
    <p class="text-center">centered text</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v1v4jaas/

In this case without inportant the text will be aligned to right. With important, the second paragraph will be centered.

Class has only a low priority against id, etc.

Comment: I see your point but you would just make the selector more specific. Which would be cleaner.

Comment: @MaxLynn: sure, I could make selector more specific. But in framework can't be more specific because framework (or framework's author) didn't know what HTML, classes and IDs you'd use in your project :-) When you use in my example code just `#aside {text-align: right}`, the second paragraph will be centered. I only wanted to show you why FWs use important.

Comment: @MaxLynn: in this case answer you marked as accepted doesn't answer to your question 'Why there is `!important`?'. It just says how to avoid using `!important`. Using framework you can't use specific selectors as Salman wrote, because, for example, `.foobar.barbaz.center {text-align: right}` will be overwriteen by FWs `.center {text-align: center !important}`. I set there `text-align: right` due to `center` class name to show you the difference, or better, which rule will be applied.

Answer (score -1):

> Using `!important` in your CSS usually means, the classes you have written do 
>   not have a proper hierarchy.

The `!important` rule overrides a particular property. But should be used only when one is helpless and it has to be overridden.

Best practice would be to use `!important` only in utility classes alone.

**eg.** Say you have a button which u want to look similar throughout your application

```
 .btn {
       margin-bottom: 0;  
       text-align: center;
       vertical-align: middle;
       touch-action: manipulation;
       cursor: pointer;  
       border: 1px solid transparent;
       padding: 6px 12px;
       font-size: 11px;
       border-radius: 4px;  
    }
```

The above definition for `.btn` holds true unless it is not wrapped by any other class which could override the `.btn` formatting which we expect to be same throughout the application. But once it is wrapped by other class like below, the final style would be totally different from your expectations.

```
<p class="format-paragraph">
   <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn"> Submit</button> 
</p>
```

Now, to make your `.btn` class super strong and to be treated with respect by the ones wrapping it, change the `.btn` definition to:

```
.btn {
           margin-bottom: 0              !important;  
           text-align: center            !important;
           vertical-align: middle        !important;
           touch-action: manipulation    !important;
           cursor: pointer               !important;  
           border: 1px solid transparent !important;
           padding: 6px 12px             !important;
           font-size: 11px               !important;
           border-radius: 4px            !important;  
        }
```

This definition would be sufficient to make your button look similar throughout the application.

The `.text-center { text-align: center !important; }` class mentioned in question is nothing but a utility here.

Know more on !important precedence [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473796/multiple-important-class-declarations-and-precedence).

Comment: You explained the `important` rule, but you missed the question. _Why_ do css frameworks use the important tag?